# Calculate time spent working with pause on SqlServer - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi guys I have such a problem with c #, then I wrote a program that calculates an employee's hours, Total Hours is calculated (Ore Fine - Ore Inizio - Pausa) Below is the query that computes . My problem is that the pause must be insertia in the hour, minute format (For example, 1.30) how do I calculate the total time that a employee worked with the query below? I hope I have explained

**OreInizio is DateTime**

**OreFine is DateTime**

**Pausa is Float**

---

Comment: What is data type of `dbo.RisorseUmane.Pausa` column ?

Comment: is float @BogdanSahlean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
  [IdRisorseUmane], 
  [IdUtente], 
  [IdCantiere],
  CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, [OreInizio], [OreFine]) - cast([Pausa] * 60 as int), 0), 114) as [TotaleOre]
from [RisorseUmane]
where [IdCantiere] = @id;
```

Comment: @RiccardoPirani I use fiddle for `select CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, '2017-07-26 12:00:00', '2017-07-26 18:00:00') - cast(1.5 * 60 as int), 0), 114)` and result is `04:30` your input data correct?

Comment: Thank you very much, I explained it too, the fact is that my client is already using the software and has entered incorrect values, however thanks

Answer (score 1):

First take the difference between those two datetime column values and the subtract it with `pausa * 60` (to make this to minutes).

**Query**

```
select [IdRisorseUmane], [IdUtente], [IdCantiere],
cast(cast((
datediff(minute, [OreInizio], [OreFine]) - ([Pausa] * 60)) as int) / 60 as varchar) + ':'  
+ right('0' + cast(cast((
datediff(minute, [OreInizio], [OreFine]) - ([Pausa] * 60)) as int) % 60 as varchar(2)), 2) 
as [TotaleOre]
from [RisorseUmane]
where [IdCantiere] = @id;
```

Don't pass values within single quotes like you did `where IdCantiere='" + IdCantiere + "'`.
It is open for SQL injection attack. Always use parameters.

Comment: If I do as you told me the result of TotaleOre you always see is wrong is -510

Comment: @RiccardoPirani : Updated my answer.

Comment: It's not right look in the pictures what's on me, Me from the negative hours

Comment: @RiccardoPirani : I updated my answer. In `DATEDIFF` function I have swapped the parameters.

Comment: Sorry my mistake the fact is that the client is already using the software i did not notice the time format is right what you said did work correctly!